# Aid on Analysing Code Execution (PHP)

Tags: php, associative-array

I'm relatively new to `php` and i have trouble understanding the following code's output:

```
function test_params($a, $b, $arrOptionalParams = array()) {
    $c = 'sat';  // default value for c
    $d = 'mat'; // default value for d

    foreach($arrOptionalParams as $key => $value) {
        ${$key} = $value;
    }
    echo "$a $b $c on the $d";
}

test_params('The', 'dog', array('c' => 'stood', 'd' => 'donkey'));
```

This produces this:
**The dog stood on the donkey**

This is my approach and what i grasped by executing the code by hand:

```
$a = 'The'
$b = 'dog'

arrOptionalParams['c']="stood"
arrOptionalParams['d']="donkey"

$c='sat'
$d='mat'

loop:
${$key}=value;

1st loop:
${$c}="stood"
$sat="stood"

2nd loop:
${$d}="donkey"
$mat="donkey"

echo "$a $b $c on the $d"
The dog sat on the mat
```

The values of c and d do change and i can't understand why. Any detailed explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note that `$$key = $value;` works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. `$c` and `$d` change because of [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

So in the loop:

```
foreach($arrOptionalParams as $key => $value) {
    ${$key} = $value;
}
```

when `$key == 'c'` the inside of the array resolves to `$c = $value;`

because `{$key}` resolves to `c` then `$c = $value` where `$value == stood` from the array passed to the function

This function seems purposefully confusing. A better approach would be more explicit:

```
function test_params($a, $b, $arrOptionalParams = array()) {
    $defaultParams = [
        'c' => 'sat',
        'd' => 'mat'    
    ];
    $params = array_merge($defaultParams, $arrOptionalParams);

    foreach($params as $key => $value) {
        $key = $value;
    }
    echo "$a $b $c on the $d";
}
```